# insert element in the dom using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using this script to insert three different `span`'s to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd `li`s.

```
$("ul li:eq(0)").prepend("<span>1</span>");
$("ul li:eq(1)").prepend("<span>2</span>");
$("ul li:eq(2)").prepend("<span>3</span>");
```

Is there a way to refactor this code to remove the redundancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it to all li tags that are there:

```
$("ul li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).prepend("<span>" + (i + 1) + "</span>");
});
```

If there are more than three li tags and you only want it done to the first three:

```
$("ul li:lt(3)").each(function(i) {
    $(this).prepend("<span>" + (i + 1) + "</span>");
});
```

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qhgad/

Comment: Actually, the second case is the same as the first, except change the selector to `$("ul li:lt(3)")`.

Comment: thanks @jfriend I was trying the same thing using for in loop but always end up getting index 0 and when i try to use i+1 it just becomes 01....

Comment: It does seem like there's always more to learn on CSS selectors.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @paul - do you understand why the parens are needed around the numbers?  You have to get the numbers added together before they are turned into a string because String(1+2) is not the same as String(1) + String(2).

Comment: @jfriend yes i understood ...its just i am concatenating 2 strings ...but i used (i+1) too...might be I am doing something wrong

Comment: @paul - You'd have to post your code for us to know what you were doing wrong with the `(i+1)`.  As you can see from the jsfiddle in my answer, the code I included works.

Comment: var selector = $("ul li");  for(i in selector){ selector.eq(i).prepend("<span>"+(i+1)+"</span>");}  this was what i was doing... and I am getting 01, 11,21

Comment: Why not use the more compact forms of one of the working examples we've provided here?  Your example has several issues.

Comment: @jfriend  yes I am now refactoring my code to use one of the solution

Comment: For reference, you cannot do: `for (i in selector)`.  selector is an object with lots of other properties that will show up in that loop.  You could use it like a traditional `for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++)` loop, but .each() does all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this like this

```
  $("ul li").prepend( function(index, html){
               return ("<span>" + (index+1) + "</span>");
   });
```

Comment: Cool idea, but that won't add the <span> tags around the content, will it?

Comment: it adds span around the number and prepends it to a li content (in the first version I omitted span tag - now added)

Comment: +1 @Michal it seems to be working and great trick instead of looping but i don't think u need to pass the html ...

Comment: it passes the current html of the element (just in case you want to do something with it). Yes tested and working.