# How to insert a DIV into another DIV with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I add a custom DIV to an already existing DIV with JQuery?

```
<div id="old-block"><div id="new-block">Lorem Ipsum</div></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http:\\api.jquery.com

Comment: $('#old-block').append('<div>'); will get you a div inside old-block

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert element in the dom using javascript or jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839328/insert-element-in-the-dom-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are many ways to insert a div inside another div.

We can use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to do it like this:

```
$('#old-block').append('<div id="new-block-2"></div>');
```

We can also use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) like this:

```
$('<div id="new-block-2"></div>').appendTo('#old-block');
```

Maybe we feel not so fancy today and want to use plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('old-block').appendChild('div');

document.getElementById('old-block').innerHTML += '<div id="new-block-2"></div>';
```

You could also try [parsing the HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4707790).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#old-block").append("<div id='dynamic'></div>");
```