# jquery place a tag around other tags

Tags: jquery

Is it possile to do the follow with jQuery?

This is the normal HTML code:

```
<figure> 
    <a href="">
        <img src="" alt="More info" title="">
    </a>
    <figcaption>More info</figcaption>
</figure>
```

But i want that jQuery do this with it:

```
<figure> 
    <a href="">
        <img src="" alt="More info" title="">
        <figcaption>More info</figcaption>
    </a>
</figure>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert element in the dom using javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839328/insert-element-in-the-dom-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/), when you have multiple element. `.each()` can be used to iterate, Here find the previous anchor using various DOM traversal methods then use the [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/).

```js
$('figcaption').each(function() {
  var prevAnchor = $(this).closest('figure').find('a'); //$(this).prev('a');
  $(this).appendTo(prevAnchor);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
  <a href="">
    <img src="" alt="More info" title="">
  </a>
  <figcaption>More info</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <a href="">
    <img src="" alt="More info" title="">
  </a>
  <figcaption>More info</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: i think `.figcaption` should be only `figcaption` (without dot)

Comment: Thats right, it works now! i have multiple figures on the site and thats going wrong now. (i get 3 times the more info under it) so i was trying it with the each(function() {} but i do something wrong i think?

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS : You can use `.append()` method to add `figcaption` inside anchor tag. see below code

```
$('figure a').append('figure figcaption');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use something like: `.appendTo();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("figcaption").appendTo("a");
});
```

```html
  
<figure>
  <a href="">
    <img src="" alt="More info" title="">
  </a>
  <figcaption>More info</figcaption>
</figure>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```